# Xamarin.Forms list through list of objects control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Which control in Xamarin can be utilized to do listing through a list of objects with the arrows left and right such as the one on the screenshot?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a like a carousel view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a control in Xmarin.forms .But you can implement it by yourself.

> in xaml

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>

  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*" />           
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
     <Image Source="xxx" x:Name="rightBtn"/>   
 </StackLayout>

 <controls:CarouselViewControl Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" InterPageSpacing="10" Position="{Binding myPosition}" ItemsSource="{Binding myItemsSource}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
         <local:MyView />
         <!-- where MyView is a ContentView -->
        </DataTemplate>
     </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
  </controls:CarouselViewControl>

  <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
     <Image Source="xxx" x:Name="leftBtn"/>
  </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

You can use  [CarouselView](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) . And change the `position` of it when you click **right** or **left** button .You can add a [tap gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) on image or use ImageButton if you want to set button image by yourself. Or you can use default arrows of CarouselView .

Answer (score 0):

If the arrows are a requirement and you don't have many items in your control (10 or less), the `CarouselView` is matching exactly your requirements. You can even show the arrows with the `ShowArrows` property.

https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

Careful though cause this component doesn't recycle its views, that's why it's good only for a small number of views.

If you have a high number of views, you use this `HorizontalListView` with `Carousel` list layout:

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms#carousel-layout

Answer (score -1):

What about the Xamarin.Forms CollectionView?

- CollectionView has a flexible layout model, **which allows data to be presented vertically or horizontally**, in a list or a grid.
- CollectionView supports single and multiple selection.
- CollectionView has no concept of cells. Instead, a data template is used to define the appearance of each item of data in the list.
- CollectionView automatically utilizes the virtualization provided by the underlying native controls.
- CollectionView reduces the API surface of ListView. Many properties and events from ListView are not present in CollectionView.
- CollectionView does not include built-in separators.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction).