# xamarin 4.2 CarouselView automatic slider

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to make automatic these changes of image on a carouselView in xamarin 4.2?  I named the xamarin forms version because in this version there is a CarouselView, so I am not able to use the old nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/2.3.0-pre1
In that old version there was a Position property which cold be set to any item in this new version included on xamarinForms 4.2, that property is missing

What I want to create is something to show a different image every 4 seconds, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You can change the `Position` of CarouselView in code behind or viewmodel  by using a timer.Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507634/xamarin-forms-list-through-list-of-objects-control

Comment: the problem is the Position property doesn't exist in xamarinforms 4.2 carouselview :) as I said above

Answer (score 2):

The `Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView` has been having a bunch of issues lately and I am not sure how exactly all of a sudden Xamarin decided to add it to the 4.2 release. Also it seems as if there are no properties in it which is weird. Anyway, I was facing weird issues with Xamarin's Carousel so I started using the `CarouselView.FormsPlugin` and it works amazingly in all situations.

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CarouselView.FormsPlugin/

Github: https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

FYI it has all the properties that XF carousel does and more:

Add the following namespace:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
```

And then use it something like this:

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl Orientation="Horizontal" InterPageSpacing="10" Position="{Binding myPosition}" ItemsSource="{Binding myItemsSource}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyView /> <!-- where MyView is a ContentView -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

For finding additional properties look for `Bindable Properties` section of the homepage at Git.

Comment: thanks, It look like a great option, I gonna try to put it into a timer to switch images automatic

Answer (score 2):

i have create automatic slider using the following code in constructor.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
            {
                if (listOfSpotlight.Count == 0 || listOfSpotlight == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                slidePosition++;
                if (slidePosition == listOfSpotlight.Count) slidePosition = 0;
                caroselView.Position = slidePosition;
                return true;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Chetan Rawat's answer or

```
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), (Func<bool>)(() =>
        {


            cView.Position = (cView.Position + 1) % imagesList.Count;

            return true;
        }));
```

*here cView is my carousel view and imageList is my list that contains the images that have to be slided in carousel view .

Happy Coding :)