# CarouselView.FormsPlugin Not Properly Working on Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I Installed **CarouselView.FormsPlugin 6.0.0** on PCL Project
It's Working Fine on Android But When I Use On Ios facing Frame height not cover fully on CarouselView ItemTemplate
Code:-

```
<StackLayout>
   <RefreshView>
      <CollectionView x:Name="CollView">
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <cv:CarouselViewControl  HeightRequest="110" AnimateTransition="False" ShowIndicators="True" Position="0" InfiniteScrolling="True" InterPageSpacing="20" VerticalOptions="Fill"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsSwipeEnabled="True" AutoplayInterval="5" IndicatorsTintColor="#E5E5E5"  ItemsSource="{Binding HomeDisplayOffers}" HorizontalIndicatorsPosition="Bottom">                               
     <cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate >                                      
         <DataTemplate >
               <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Frame Padding="0" HeightRequest="110" "HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <!--- Binding Source Code --->
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout
        </DataTemplate >
    </cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>                                      
</cv:CarouselViewControl>
          </DataTemplate>
      </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
   </CollectionView>
  </RefreshView>
</StackLayout>
```

[pls Check the Attached Screenshot.. **Some Frame Coverup and Some Frame Getting Space on Bottom**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1akb.png)

Comment: Had you tried the CarouselView just like the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data)?

Comment: i tried  official document @Liyun Zhang . but i have issue with SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" SnapPointsAlignment="Center" When swipe the carousel

Comment: What the issue is with them and you can post a new question or edit the current question to show the problem.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Can you have Code For Auto Sliding for Carousel Inner of CollectionView ItemTemplate

Comment: You can check this case :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727073/xamarin-4-2-carouselview-automatic-slider

Comment: this is single carousel but i have multiple carousel on CollectionView Template So How Dynamic Carousel Auto Sliding

Comment: i updated the sample code .. pls check above sample Like wise i wrote code on my project @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: The point is not at the number. You can gave each Carousel a name and change their position in the .cs  just as the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with the control and everything to do with your XAML code, Giving it a static height is going to obviously do this, options that you have are quite simple to be honest get a container that covers the whole frame like Absolute or Grid

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <cv:CarouselViewControl AnimateTransition="False" ShowIndicators="True" Position="0" InfiniteScrolling="True" InterPageSpacing="20"   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" VerticalOptions="Fill"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsSwipeEnabled="True" AutoplayInterval="5" IndicatorsTintColor="#E5E5E5"  ItemsSource="{Binding HomeDisplayOffers}" HorizontalIndicatorsPosition="Bottom">                               
 <cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate >                                      
     <DataTemplate >
                <Frame Padding="0">
                    <!--- Binding Source Code --->
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout
    </DataTemplate >
  </cv:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>                                      
 </cv:CarouselViewControl>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Thank u @FreakyAli for Ur Valuable Answer . I Will Try and Ping to Status

Comment: Hi @FreakyAli Above Solution Couldn't Solve this Issue .. i thing problem was CarouselView.FormsPlugin

Comment: Did you update the code based on your view? or did you just copy paste it?

Comment: i just update the code as per mentioned above .. i put absolute layout, flag and also try to grid. Both Case i facing Same Issue

Comment: Can u pls share the CarouselView Free Plugin for Xamarin ?

Comment: Can you have Code For Auto Sliding for Carousel Inner of CollectionView ItemTemplate